# for loop with cor.test over many categories

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I am trying to write a loop in R that will cycle through 3 different species to calculate the correlation between two continuous variables (Redness and VarNormAbund).

My loop is running, but the output for each of the 3 species is the same, which makes me think the loop is getting stuck at the first species.

```
 cor.test.redness<-lapply(unique(test$Species), function(x){cor.test(test$Redness, test$VarNormAbund)})
```

Data structure:
Species are in the first column. I would like the loop to extract each species and do a cor.test between Redness and VarNormAbund.
There should be an output for each category. So 3 outputs in the list.

Am I missing an argument that tells the loop to do each Species?

Also, is there any way to have the output be a `data.frame` instead of a list?

Any advice would be appreciated, I do not have much experience with loops.

```
Species<-c("A","B","C","A","B","C","A","B","C")
Redness<-c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)
VarNormAbund<-c(1.6, 0,0,12.5,0,1,1.37, 2.74, 0)
test<-data.frame(Species, Redness, VarNormAbund)
```

cheers.

Comment: Where is the `for` loop? I only see `lapply`.

Comment: @Parfait, I believe `lapply` implies a loop over the elements of a list.

Comment: @gung - I understand behind the scenes lapply is a loop (a vectorized version) but I like other readers may expected an explicit `for` loop. It was even tagged as such.

Comment: @Parfait, true. This does set you up to expect something more explicit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you get the same results for all the three species is that even you are looping through the unique species, you didn't subset your data so your test is still on the whole data set, a simple fix would be:

```
cor.test.redness<-lapply(unique(test$Species), function(x){
                         cor.test(test[test$Species == x, ]$Redness, 
                                  test[test$Species == x, ]$VarNormAbund)})
```

If you want the output to be a data frame, you can extract the coefficients from the correlation test result and put them in a data frame and then `rbind` the results. So if, for example, you want data frame of `p.value` and `correlation coefficient`, you can do:

```
cor.test.redness<-do.call(rbind, lapply(unique(test$Species), function(x){
                    cor.result <- cor.test(test[test$Species == x, ]$Redness, 
                                           test[test$Species == x, ]$VarNormAbund); 
                    data.frame(p.Value = cor.result$p.value, cor = cor.result$estimate)
                   }))

cor.test.redness
#        p.Value         cor
# cor  0.9884892 -0.01808019
# cor1 0.3333333  0.86602540
# cor2 1.0000000  0.00000000
```

You can also add a column to specify the species in the result data frame. But I believe you can figure that part out, so leave it to you.

*Note*: this type of subsetting can be potentially slow, if your dataset is large and the performance is an issue, you can try to do the test using `data.table` or `dplyr`'s fast groupby feature.

Comment: Both the loop and data frame conversion work perfectly! Thank you for explaining what I was missing in the loop!

Answer (score 0):

We can do this easily using group by operations.

```
library(data.table)
lst <- setDT(test)[, list(list(cor.test(Redness, VarNormAbund))), by = Species]$V1
```

or if we need to extract the pvalue, just do

```
setDT(test)[, list(pval = cor.test(Redness, VarNormAbund)$p.value), by = Species]
# Species      pval
#1:       A 0.9884892
#2:       B 0.3333333
#3:       C 1.0000000
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun for your help as well!